# How to simulate a page opened in Wechat?

Tags: web, wechat

I am working on a webpage and it works fine on Safari on iPhone. However, when the page is opened in WeChat (opened by clicking a link in chat), it has some problems.

Because the problems only exist in WeChat, I was wondering is there a way to simulate the WeChat so that I can debug it?

Otherwise I can only make some changes in code, then deploy, then view it in WeChat, which is very inefficient.

Based on comment, I provide the actual problem here:
I'm using [Slick](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) in my page. In WeChat, when I swipe slides, there is obvious lagging.

Thank you!

Comment: Would you explain more over the problems you are experiencing? Error messages, screenshots, how to reproduce, test links, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wxdebugeer tool provided by wechat for debugging.

Link : [Wechat tool](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki?t=resource/res_main&id=mp1455784140&token=&lang=zh_CN)

Whatever the problem related to webpage development for wechat can be tested using this.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I cannot open a valid page with the link. Can you check that?

Comment: Do you have a link to load in my end and check?

Comment: Oh, I mean I cannot open the link(Wechat tool) you provided. Can you check that?

Comment: `https://mp.weixin.qq.com/wiki?t=resource/res_main&id=mp1455784140&token=&lang=zh_CN` Refer this.

Comment: Do we have to create a WeChat account? I was hoping to be able to load a URL and see how it looks like in the App without having to install it or register. Specially since this is just a one time thing.

Comment: Dont have to create a Official WeChat account, but need a wechat personal social account, since the tool will ask to scan qr code - you can use your friends access to.